# Changing badge logo for notifications on lock screen in Windows Store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

In the Package.appxmanifest under Notifications I have changed the badge logo to a new 24x24 pixel logo, but it seems like I'm stuck with the old logo on the lock screen no matter what.

In the manifest the new logo is declared:

```
   <LockScreen Notification="badgeAndTileText" BadgeLogo="Assets\BadgeLogoNew.png" />
```

But it is still the old logo that is shown in the lock screen.

I have even searched my computer and deleted all instances of the old logo, but it is still shown in the lock screen.

If I deploy for remote debugging on a "clean" PC, the new badge logo is shown.

Any hints would be appreciated.

**Solution found:**
Change the app name in Package.appxmanifest and in Package.StoreAssociation, then deploy again and the new badge logo will be displayed on the lock screen. Remember to change back the app name.